# IIS only works on localhost

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2, from AWS Amazon EC2
But it works only on localhost.
When i try to go on my public IP, it returns this error:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AWS blocked the port so you need to configure that. Also need to enable the ports on Windows Firewall.

Comment: and how to configure that?